# 'dragenter' won't fire when browser window is maximised in a React component

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

> I've come to realise that this is probably a Bug or known issue (not confirmed) in the native drag and drop API as i've tried using `react-dnd` package with HTML5 DragandDrop API as the backend and the issue still exists when using reponsive width `width: 100%`. Using Media Query to have different widths for different screen sizes also doesn't work, the same issue exists. So, we only have to use fixed width no matter the screen size or use a responsive width and live with this bug. I have to Say goodbye to responsive layout for my list view.

When the window isn't maximised everything works fine. But if I suddenly maximise the window to fullSize, `'dragenter'` does fire on the items but ***only if we drag over along the item's length equal to the length of the items before the window was maximised***. It doens't happen always, but it does happen frequently. I've spent too many hours trying to trouble shoot but i'm at my wits end and I require some external help.

**NOTE:** I've noticed, If I leave the window maximised for a few seconds (5-6 seconds) it resolves itself and dragenter works again. But will bug again for new window sizes. This is a strange behaviour and I don't know what is causing it.

**Steps that can reproduce the bug:**

- launch the app in a new window which is not maximised,  while Keeping a rough note of the width of the window.
- Maximise the window and try dragging an item over another item along the width but on the **excess width area** `(max width - small width)`  of an item.
- if it wasn't reproduced, change the window size to a new small window size and then maximise the window again. Or close the tab and try again on a new tab.

**Things I've tried that didn't work:**

- Used Refs to track item's position instead of state.
- Added preventDefault to handlers
- Added stopPropagation to handlers
- force state update to refresh the component.
- Reload page on window resize.
- Disabled all chrome extensions.
- Restarted Chrome.
- Using media query to set varying fixed widths for different screen sizes.

**What works**

- Using a particular fixed width for all screen sizes.

Here's a codesandbox demo where you can check it for your self. Make sure to open the preview in a new tab and try the steps above:
[Codedsandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-drag-and-drop-bug-w1j3db?file=/src/ListSort.jsx:0-1985)

```
import { useState } from "react";

const ListSort = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    "Apple",
    "Mango",
    "Bananana",
    "Pineapple",
    "Orange"
  ]);
  const [draggedPos, setDraggedPos] = useState();
  const [enterPos, setEnterPos] = useState();

  const handleDragStart = (e, index) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setDraggedPos((state) => index);
  };

  const handleDragEnter = (e, index) => {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (enterPos) return;
    else setEnterPos((state) => index);

    if (draggedPos !== index) {
      const newItems = [...items];
      const dragItem = newItems[draggedPos];
      newItems.splice(draggedPos, 1);
      newItems.splice(index, 0, dragItem);

      setDraggedPos((state) => index);
      setItems((state) => newItems);
    }
  };

  const handleDragLeave = (e, index) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    setEnterPos((state) => null);
  };

  const handleDragEnd = (e, index) => {
    e.stopPropagation();

    resetPositionStates();
  };

  function resetPositionStates() {
    setEnterPos((state) => null);
    setDraggedPos((state) => null);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
        <h3>REACT DRAG AND DROP BUG</h3>
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              draggable
              onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, index)}
              onDragEnter={(e) => handleDragEnter(e, index)}
              onDragLeave={(e) => handleDragLeave(e, index)}
              onDragEnd={(e) => handleDragEnd(e, index)}
              style={{
                padding: "5px",
                color: "white",
                backgroundColor: "purple",
                width: "100%",
                marginTop: "10px",
                height: "28px"
              }}
            >
              {item}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ListSort;
```